# Переносы строк не сохраняются в БД

Tags: php, html, база-данных

Есть поле, в нем переношу строки, в БД тоже текст сохраняется с переносами, но когда выбираю из БД, то они удаляются, получается просто линейный текст

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Теги `<br />` надо вставлять. Выполните `nl2br` (строка на обработку) для каждой строки, которую пишите в базу.

Answer (score 1):

При выводе текста можно менять `preg_replace('/\n/i','<br />',$string);`

Answer (score 0):

Надо в БД заливать сразу отформатированный тегами текст.

Если вы используете **форму** и тег **textarea**, то выводите полученный текст в теги **pre** и посмотрите атрибут [wrap](http://htmlbook.ru/html/textarea/wrap)

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <textarea wrap="hard" name="txtArea" cols="20" rows="10"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value=" отправить" />
</form>
<br/>
<br/>
<pre><?php echo $_POST['txtArea'] ?></pre>
```